# Uncaught Error: Unexpected directive 'MatFormField' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: datepicker, angular-material, angular7

I Want to use Angular Material Date picker but I am getting this error.

> Uncaught Error: Unexpected directive 'MatFormField' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

app.component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {MatFormField} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MatFormField
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

To import components and directives etc, you import their modules, not the actual components and directives. So you need to import `MatFormFieldModule` instead of `MatFormField`:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MatFormFieldModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much